# Export list and NumberForm

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have the following code

```
list = {3.45, 3., 5, 3*10^4}
formList = NumberForm[list, {4, 5}]
Export["./list", list, "List"]
Export["./formList", formList, "List"]
```

Now the file **list** has each number in different lines but the file **formList** has one line in Mathematica list format. My question is how to get the new line behaviour while also having used `NumberForm`.

Comment: Consider `formList // InputForm` as see that `NumberForm` is taking in the `List`. You want `NumberForm` on each value in the list. Try `formList = NumberForm[#, {4, 5}] & /@ list`.

Comment: Which version are you using? I am on 11.1 and `ExportString[formList, "List"]` does show the trailing zeros. Haven't looked specifically at `Export`.

Comment: @Edmund I',m using 11.1 but have no idea what's going on. This example works correctly but the actual code I'm using exports no trailing zeros. Probably something I'm neglecting...